# Obtener las URLs de todos los elementos <a> dentro de un div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quiero copiar las urls (href) de todos los "a" dentro de un div, pero este tiene muchos elementos anidados. ¿Cómo seria para copiarlo?

Éste seria el ejemplo:

```html
<div id="enlaces">
    <div id="tabla">
        <div >
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http:www.google.com">></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">

                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr >
                                        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Intenté con `getElemenById`, pero copia todo. Y sólo quiero copiar los "a".

Comment: amigo describe mejor lo que quieres, no es muy entendible, copiarlos a donde?, cual seria el resultado final? @hblackpro

Comment: quiero guardarlos en un vector. solo eso

Comment: Quizás lo que buscas es la método "cloneNode" pasando el parámetro "true" para que incluya los elementos hijos.
Ojo, en alguna versión de IE he comprobado que no copia los atributos.

Comment: Lo mejor es usar lo que te recomienda Luiggi, yo hice algo parecido para sacar todas las imágenes en alta calidad de mi Pinterest sin tener que ir una por una, hice un script en javascript que guarda todas las urls de alta definición de un tablero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para seleccionar sólo ciertos elementos puedes utilizar [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Por ejemplo:

```js
var as = document.querySelectorAll('#tabla a');
```

Eso te devuelve un listado de nodos, que es como un arreglo, y puedes usar eso para ponerlos donde necesites.

---

Para sacar sólo las urls luego puedes iterar en el arreglo asi:

```js
var urls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
   urls.push(as[i].href);
}
```

Comment: me devuelve un arreglo pero asi: <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                                            
                                        </a>

Comment: como seria para que solo salga facebook.com?

Comment: sin los <a></a>

Comment: Tienes que iterar sobre los elementos y sacar los valores de href. Algo asi como añadire en la respuesta

Comment: alguna idea para investigar?

Comment: Ya lo puse en mi respuesta.

Comment: excelente. me sirve de lujo

Answer (score 0):

Perdòn, no puedo hacer comentarios. No logro comprender bien lo que vos planteàs; asì que si podès hacèmelo saber y edito la respuesta en funciòn a eso.

Lo que inicialmente comprendo, es que querès tomar todos los elementos *anchor (a)* y hacer una copia de los mismos... ahora bien, creo que lo que vos querès hacer es clonar.

Para eso podès usar el mètodo "cloneNode" sobre cada elemento  del . Para seleccionar esos elementos, podès usar el mètodo "querySelectorAll":

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#tabla > a')
```

Eso te va a devolver un objeto NodeList (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) sobre el cuàl podès iterar con un *for*. A los elementos de esa lista accedès mediante un ìndice, como en un Array normal.

Ahora bien, el mètodo querySelectorAll recibe un selector CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). En el caso anterior, 'div#tabla > a' indica que se seleccione y devuelva un NodeList con todos los elementos *a* dentro del *div* con el ID 'tabla' (indicado luego de la almohadilla/numeral #).

Lo que queda por hacer, es iterar sobre esa lista de nodos, y clonando cada elemento. Voy a suponer que querès obtener una lista de esos clones, y lo voy a poner en una funciòn, porque la verdad no conozco el contexto:

```
'use strict';

const COPY_CHILD_NODES = true; // En caso de que tenga childs, clonarlos tambièn.

const clonedNodes = (css_selector) => {
   let clones = [];
   const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(css_selector);
   for (let node_index = 0; node_index < nodes.length; node_index++) {
      clones.push(nodes[node_index].cloneNode(COPY_CHILD_NODES));
   }
   return clones;
}

const cloned_a = clonedNodes('div#tabla > a');
```

"cloned_a" contendrìa las copias de esos elementos , en un array comùn, y deberìas iterar sobre esos clones y hacer lo que quieras, por ejemplo, agregarlos a otro elemento:

```
cloned_a.forEach(element => {
   someParentElement.appendChild(element);
});
```

Saludos :) Si no es esto lo que buscabas, por favor avisame y edito como corresponda.

Abrazo che n.n

Comment: gracias. me resulto util

Comment: De nada che :) despuès seleccionà alguna respuesta que sea correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar

```
var elts = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

donde te devolvera un array con todos los "a"

Comment: hola. si da un arreglo. pero como seria para que solo salga el enlace sin las etiquetas a

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute("href"); asi de esta forma te dara el primer "a" que encuentre. Si queres todos usa un for o foreach y metele los href en un nuevo array

Answer (score -1):

jQuery te lo soluciona en un santiamen, sin array ni nada.

```
$('a').each(function(index, el) {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

un saludo,